# How can I remove showing undefined in the console for the line of code?

Tags: javascript, function

The following line of code output's the word undefined in the console. How can I remove this? I am very new to programming.

Output:

> You are not getting enough sleep 
>   undefined

Code:

```js
function getSleepHours(day) {
  if (day === 'monday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'tuesday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'wednesday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'thursday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'friday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'saturday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'sunday') {
    return 5;
  }
}
const getActualSleepHours = () =>
  getSleepHours('monday') +
  getSleepHours('tuesday') +
  getSleepHours('wednesday') +
  getSleepHours('thursday') +
  getSleepHours('friday') +
  getSleepHours('saturday') +
  getSleepHours('sunday');
const idealSleepHours = 56;
let let2 = getActualSleepHours();

function calculateSleepDebt() {
  if (let2 >= idealSleepHours) {
    console.log('You are getting sound sleep');
  } else {
    console.log('You are not getting enough sleep');
  }
}
console.log(calculateSleepDebt()
```

Comment: Since `calculateSleepDebt()` does not return anything, try not to log the result from calling it.

Comment: If a `function` does not explicitly `return` a value, it by default returns `undefined`.

Comment: Just don't call **calculateSleepDebt()** with console.log()

Comment: Missing ); from end of last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to run `console.log()` a second time, you are already running it inside your `calculateSleepDebt()` function. So basically you are telling the browser to log something inside the log and this is causing the undefined part.

You can just call your function `calculateSleepDebt()` and it will print to your console itself. So the last line of your code should just be `calculateSleepDebt()` and not `console.log(calculateSleepDebt()` (btw you missed `);` here)

Comment: I think he missed ')' not ');' as ';' is optional in JS :p

Comment: You are right, it is optional but I find it more helpful to point out even `;` to new programmers because this will help them avoid future mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call calculateSleepDebt() inside console.log then it should return something printable for instance

```
function calculateSleepDebt() {
  if (let2 >= idealSleepHours) {
    return 'You are getting sound sleep';
  } else {
    return 'You are not getting enough sleep';
  }
}
```

If you don't want to change calculateSleepDebt() then replace

```
console.log(calculateSleepDebt()
```

with

```
calculateSleepDebt()
```

What happens here, is the call to calculateSleepDebt() logs the sentence you want but the function doesn't return anything so

```
console.log(calculateSleepDebt()
```

logs undifined.